# php strip_tags: allows <br />?

Tags: php, tags, strip

How it is possible to allow `<br />` in strip_tags() or any way I can get around to it?

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test <br />paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p>, <a>, <br />
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a><br />');
echo "\n";

// Allow <br /> only
echo strip_tags($text, '<br />');
?>
```

result:

```
Test paragraph. Other text
<p>Test paragraph.</p> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>
Test paragraph. Other text
```

Thanks,
Lau

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't use a self-closing tag name? `echo strip_tags($text, '<br>');`

The `strip_tags()` function's `allowable_tags` argument takes the allowed tags in the form `<tagname>` The reason your code didn't work was because you used `<br />` instead of `<br>`.

Comment: I tough a valid br tag was always self-closing !?

Comment: Only in XHTML, not HTML which is what strip_tags parses.

Comment: Just for others who want to allow several tags, you add them like this: `strip_tags($text, '<br><p><b>');`

Answer (score 6):

`strip_tags` is not intended as a security measure, and using it with `allowable_tags` is definitely insecure, as it'll let through event handler and other harmful attributes.

If you want to allow user input with a few whitelisted elements and attributes you'll need to use a HTML-sanitising library with a proper HTML parser. See for example [HTML purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

It's usually better for user comments not to give the user control over the HTML markup at all, but instead to accept raw text, HTML-escape it on output, and do replacements to generate markup from text (eg: `\n` -> `<br>`, `\n\n` -> `</p><p>`, link detection).

Answer (score 2):

Whitespace is also not allowed in tags: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php (see 2nd note)

Answer (score 1):

Ya you can mix one or more tag to be striped same time.

```
string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )
```

check documentation

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

if you want to strip new line as well solution will be before stripping you can use **nl2br**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

so

```
echo strip_tags(nl2br($text), '<br>');
```